# easeOutQuart implementation with equal operator in mathematical function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math

I don't understand this implementation of the easeOutQuart function from this repository: https://gist.github.com/CGamesPlay/8628541:

```
easeOutQuart: function (t) {
    return -1 * ((t=t/1-1)*t*t*t - 1);
},
```

I can't figure out how works the `(t=t/1-1)` term. The equal operator is the assignement operator, why is it in the middle of this mathematical function?

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: works like 1. `x = t/1`, 2. `y = x - 1` , 3. `z = -1(y*y*y*y - 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignment in JS is not just an assignment, it's also [a returning operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment#return_value). `something=bleh` returns `bleh`, so that you can do things like `const a = b = c = 100` and all three variables are now 100, with each assignment "returning" the assigned value to whatever code is around it.

As such, `t=t/1 - 1` is both an assignment *and* returns the assigned value, with the remaining `t` later in the same statement using that newly assigned value rather than the originally provided `t`.

Rewriting things to be obvious, this:

```js
function easeOutQuart(t) {
  return -1 * ((t=t/1-1)*t*t*t - 1);
}
```

is the equivalent of:

```js
function easeOutQuart(t) {
  const s = t - 1;
  return -(s ** 4 - 1);
}
```

Because `t/1` is just `t`, and JS has sensible syntax for "to the power of 4". Also, we're using a normal minus sign instead of "multiplying by -1" because that's literally what the minus sign is for.

Which in modern JS you could even rewrite as:

```js
function easeOutQuart(t, s = t-1) {
  return -(s ** 4 - 1);
}
```

Does the code you show work? Absolutely, it's perfectly valid. But is it "clever for clever's sake instead of being good code"? The same answer. It is incredibly unlikely that this function is somehow a critical bottleneck in anyone's code, and relying on a mid-evaluation-assignment to change the value on the active parameter is questionable at best. You'd need some damn good benchmarks to show it's worth it.

Comment: @MikePomax, Thank you so much. that's the best answer I could imagine. Therefore, there are still two points. Why dividing by 1, `t/1` is equal to `t`, no ? I'm surprised by this syntax : `easeOutQuart(t, s=t/1-1)` in your answer. The function is expected a single parameter and the second one is automatically calculated, am I right?

Comment: Presumably the `t/1` is an artifact from whatever more generic code they initially wrote, but you'll have to ask the actual code author(s). As for the suprising syntax: JS allows for default argument assignment, and "any preceding argument" is part of the assignment scope. So it's a function that takes 2 arguments, but you only need to supply one, and the second one will automatically be assigned a value.

Comment: Presumably the `t/1` is an artifact from whatever more generic code they initially wrote, but you'll have to ask the actual code author(s). As for the suprising syntax: JS allows for [default argument assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters), and "any preceding argument" is part of the assignment scope. So it's a function that takes 2 arguments, but you only need to supply one, and the second one will automatically be assigned a value.